# grow or shrink UIImageView frame to fit the entire iPhone screen via AutoLayout?

Tags: uiimageview, ios6, autolayout

So I'm still getting accustomed to the world of Auto Layout in iOS 6 and it's been a fun (or in plain English -- tough) migration coming over from strings & struts.

I have a UIImageView that's the background for a game I'm working on.  Here's what a regular 3.5" Retina Display looks like in Interface Builder:

[image: iphone 4 retina display]

but if I change the "Size" pop-up in the Simulated Metrics field for the content view to "Retina 4 Full Screen", here's what I see:

[image: iphone 5 retina display]

And you can see the ugly black bar appearing along the bottom edge of the simulated iPhone 5 screen.  This same ugly black bar makes it over to the compiled app running in the iPhone 5 simulator.

Are there any attributes or constraints I can apply via Interface Builder to get the UIImageView's frame to size correctly for the appropriate iPhone device screen size?

Or do I have to enter in constraints via code? (ugh)

I've watched the three WWDC videos and if the engineers covered the topic of sizing a view to fit a parent, they must have glossed over it really fast because I've haven't yet found or heard a decent method to get both UIImageView and NSImageView to size correctly to their parent views under both the iOS and MacOS side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you're showing here, I think that what you want to do is drag the image to meet the bottom of the superview so that it takes up all of the space you want. On the bottom right in the IB view you will see a small, grey pill-shaped set of 3 buttons. Click the center one (once you have your imageView selected). It's the one that looks a little like this: |--|. It will bring up a list of constraints. Once you have done that, select "Bottom Space to Superview". You should then be able to switch between phones and have the image resize automatically.

Comment: thanks for responding @Sneagan!  I followed your instructions: making sure to set both "Top Space to Superview" and "Bottom Space to Superview" on the UIImageView, but when I changed the (simulated) content view height in XCode's Interface Builder from 3.5" to 4", the black bar at the bottom remains. There's no other constraints on the UIImageView or on the superview, as far as I can tell. Very curious!

Comment: Sorry! Wrote that on the go. I edited the answer to fix. I think doing Only "Bottom Space to Superview" should solve your problem!

Comment: Hi @Sneagan... took me a bit of time to come back and award the checkbox, but it looks like your recommendation worked out great! Thanks muchly.